# Positive semi definite hessian at a critical point

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

If the hessian evaluated at a critical point is positive (negative) definite, then we can conclude that it's a local minimum (maximum) there. If the hessian is indefinite (both negative and positive eigenvalues), then it's a saddle point.

What happens if the Hessian is positive SEMI-definite? According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test, it seems it is inconclusive whether the point is a max/min/saddle point, but I am wondering why this is the case. If the hessian was globally positive semi-definite, then the function is convex, and hence a local minima exists. But in the current *local* case, why can't we say that if the Hessian at a critical point is PSD, then it's a local minima?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same as the case in one dimensional optimization of the second derivative being 0. Namely, 0 is not a local minimum of the function $x^3$, and an analogous multivariate example to work out is the function $f(x,y)=x^3+y^2$.

Comment: But what about the case where it is positive semi definite?

Comment: @David it is positive semi definite here. Work out the hessian evaluated at 0, which will be diagonal, and you’ll see what I mean.

Comment: Ah the hessian evaluated at (0,0), the critical point, is a 2x2 matrix with zeros everywhere except for the lower right element which is 2. So this is PSD. So at this point, we do not know if it is a max/min/saddle point based on the second derivative test?

Comment: @David exactly, this works the exact same way as the one dimensional case (and reduces to the classic example when you restrict yourself to looking only at the x-axis

Comment: In the 1-D case, if the second derivative is zero, isn't it conclusive that the critical point is a saddle point? I'm kind of having a hard time seeing the cross-over between 1D and multi-D.

Comment: @David in the one-d case, the second derivative being 0 is also inconclusive(I’ve never heard the term saddle point in the context of one dimensions—only to describe a point which is a minimum when restricted to one direction and maximum in another) for example, a function like $x^4$ can have the second derivative in the 1d case be 0 at 0 and still be a local minimum.

Comment: Oh interesting. I actually thought saddle point came from the 1-D case, but my memory on that is a bit hazy.